Connecting a centos vm (nfs client) with ubuntu laptop (nfs server)
Can you connect nfs between a Linux VM and a Linux computer? so far I have tried configuring the NFS server on my Ubuntu laptop and followed every step, then I did the same to the NFS client on Centos 9 stream running on the VM on my computer. but when I export the folder from my Ubuntu laptop it brings this message

root@adriannet:/mynfsfolder# exportfs -rv
exportfs: No file systems exported!

I have created /mynfsfolder on my Ubuntu machine and added files a, b, c, and d meaning the folder is not empty
root@adriannet:/mynfsfolder# ls -l
total 16
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Sep  5 15:24 a
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Sep  5 15:25 b
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Sep  5 15:25 c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Sep  5 15:25 d

I have modified /etc/exports as shown
/mynfsfolder *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
The nfs-service is running on my Ubuntu laptop, the same with rpcbind on Centos 9 Stream
A help will be much appreciated
